# I don't know what I've done to my functions.php

Tags: php

I have no idea what I've done wrong but this is breaking my site and bringing up errors.

```
function token_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_style(‘bootstrap - style’, get_template_directory_uri() . ‘ / css / bootstrap . css’);
    wp_enqueue_style(‘main - style’, get_stylesheet_uri());

   wp_enqueue_script(‘jquery’);
   wp_enqueue_script(‘bootstrap - script’, get_template_directory_uri() . ‘ / js / bootstrap . min . js’, array(), ‘1.0.0’, true);
}


add_action(‘wp_enqueue_scripts’, ‘token_scripts’);
```

Any idiot proof help would be greatly appreciated. I am a noob and really need you to be gentle with me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: In which editor/tool did you write your code?

Comment: What OS are you running your PHP in? If it's UNIX, does your file have DOS (aka Windows) line-endings? This will almost always cause a problem in UNIX. If so, run dos2unix on the file.

Comment: This `‘` Your quotes are Rich Text quotes.  Which are not UTF-8, I see these a lot from MSWord or other Office programs.  Use real quotes `'`

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for answering. My editor is phpstorm by jetbrains and I am on a mac. I use serverpress for my localhost.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix - Thank you very much for your advice.

You were quite right. I wrote the wp-enqueue scripts into pages which is the mac word processor and then copy/pasted them into my editor.

I deleted the code and re-wrote manually and it is working perfectly now.

If I know how to thumbs up or mark your answer as best , I would do it.

Thanks again.

Comment: Lesson learned; use a programming-oriented editor! :-)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may have used some kind of office program (MSword) or some other form of "rich text editor" when coding this:

```
 wp_enqueue_style(‘bootstrap - style’, get_template_directory_uri() . ‘ / css / bootstrap . css’);
```

If you look closely the quotes are `‘` a curly quote, which I think is non-UTF8. Compare to the below code:

```
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap - style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css');
```

Sometimes you can just copy and paste it into a plain text editor (like notepad++) and that will convert them.  Of course you can just manually edit them too.

Those quotes have been the cause of much irritation for me, personally, and I am sure for many a web developer... lol